# order of Processes in this special case of round robin scheduling

Tags: scheduled-tasks, round-robin

*(this was a question asked in the 5th semester of my computer engineering degree)*

What will the order of process execution be in the following scenario, given that the scheduling used is Round Robin?

QUANTUM SIZE = 4

Process----Arrival time----Burst time

A---0---3

B---1---5

C---3---2

D---9---5

E---12---5

**My real doubt comes at time 9. At this point, A and C have finished execution. B is in the queue and D has just entered. Which one will be executed first? B or D?**

should the overall order be A-B-C-D-E-B-D-E
or A-B-C-B-D-E-D-E?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In round robin processes are executed for a time period called `Quantum` you haven't mentioned it. Still there is no problem. `Round Robin` algorithm says that each process will get equal time period for execution in a circular fashion. At the point of ambiguity, it implements `First Come First Serve` method. You are mentioning a deadlock situation here. `B` should com first. Here are few references: [Word Definition](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/round-robin) [a simple example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling#Process_scheduling)

Answer (score 1):

the order of exe will be A-B-C-B-D-E-D-E, because at time 3 i.e. after exe of a ready queue have B , C in same order , so B is executed till time 7 (as TQ < burst time of b ) and B is queued back in circular queue (ready queue) as follows A-B-C-*B*
and  at time 7 c will execute till time 10 , while exe of c d arrived at ready queue at time 9 therefore queue like A-B-C-B-D...
final chart will be

Q=     | A | B | C | B | D | E | D | E |
T=     |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
       0   3   7  10  11  15  19  20  21

Answer (score 0):

> Round Robin scheduling is similar to FCFS (**F**irst **C**ome
>   **F**irst **S**erve) scheduling, but preemption is added. The ready queue is treated as a circular queue. The CPU scheduler goes around
>   the ready queue, allocating CPU to each process for a time interval of
>   up to 1 time quantum.
>   *Operating System Concepts (Silberschatz)*

Now in your case,
the Gantt Chart will look like this:

```
A   |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |  B  |  D  |  E  |
0   3     7     9     13    17    18    19   20
```

Notice in this case at first we consider FCFS and start with process **A** (arrival time 0 ms) then we continue dispatching each process based on their arrival time (the same sequence in which you have listed in the question)
, for 1 **time quantum** (4 ms each).

If the burst time of a process is less than the time quantum then it releases the CPU voluntarily otherwise preemption is applied.

So, the scheduling order will be :

`A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> B -> D -> E`